# Show not logged users processes linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, command

I am doing a bash script and i am essaying to show not logged users processes,which are typically daemon processes, for this,in the exercise, they recommend me:

> To process the command line, we will use the cut command, which allows
>   selecting the different columns of the list through a filter.

I used:

```
ps -A | grep -v w
ps -A | grep -v who 

ps -A | grep -v $USER
```

but trying all these options all the processes of all users are printed in the output file, and I only want the processes of users who are not logged.

I appreciate your help

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -v w` will remove lines matching the regular expression `w` (which is simply anything which contains the string `w`).  To run the *command* `w` you have to say so; but as hinted in the instructions, you will also need to use `cut` to post-process the output.

So as not to give the answer away completely, here's rough pseudocode.

```
w | cut something >tempfile
ps -A | grep -Fvf tempfile
```

It would be nice if you could pass the post-processed results of `w` in a pipe, but standard input is already tied to `ps -A`.  If you have a shell which supports [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), you can use that.

```
ps -A | grep -Fvf <(w | cut something)
```

Unfortunately, the output from `w` is not properly machine-readable -- you will properly want to cut out the header line(s), too. (On my machine, there are two header lines. Yours might differ.) You'll probably learn a bit of Awk later on in the course, but until then, maybe something like

```
ps -A | grep -Fvf <(w | tail -n +3 | cut something)
```

This still doesn't completely handle all possible situations.  What if someone's account name is `grep`?

Comment: w | cut something >tempfile , something  could be $USER?, it doesn ' t run with that and show me all processes

Comment: No, `something` here is a placeholder for options to `cut` to tell it which fields to cut and how to find field separators.  See the manual page.

Comment: Hello @triplee i used cut -d, but it gives me the error "doesn't exist the name of file

Comment: Doesn't look right. The separator between columns in this data is not a comma, and that error message would only happen if you actually gave it a file name.